# Elements below an element with relative position and negative top value remain where they are

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have 3 elements one on top of another. If I give the second (pink) one a relative position and negative top value it goes above the first one. But the third one doesn't "follow", remaining exactly where it is:

HTML:

```
<div id='div1'>text</div>
<div id='div2'>text</div>
<div id='div3'>text</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    padding: 50px;
}
#div1 {
    background: yellow;
}
#div2 {
    background: pink;
    position: relative;
    top: -50px;
}
#div3 {
    background: gray;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dyg86qbq/)

How to make the third one and any other elements below it "follow" the pink element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not really sure what you want to achieve, but I hope I get this right.
give the following CSS in your third `<div>`.Just check :)

```
   position: relative;
   top: -50px;
```

or,

```
   margin-top: -50px;
```

another way,

```
div {
    padding: 50px;
}
#div1 {
    background: yellow;
    width:100%;
}
#div2 {
    background: pink;
    position: relative;
    top: -50px;
    width:100%;
    float:left;
}
#div3 {
    background: gray;
    width:100%;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sarbaz/ud890vgb/)

Answer (score 10):

You can't achive what you want with `top` CSS rule. Negative value at `top` is not affecting the below element. You have to use `margin-top` instead.

So try:

```
#div2 {
    background: pink;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -70px; /*Here change the top to margin-top*/
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/dyg86qbq/1/)

Answer (score 2):

You should use

```
margin-top: -50px;
```

Answer (score 2):

just changing top to margin-top will do the trick

Answer (score 2):

They don't follow because you are using absolute positions. If you want to implement the behaviour you describe you need to use blocks.

```
#div2, #div3 {
    margin-top: -50px;
}
```

Although I don't recommend you to use negative margins. Only use them as the last resource.

Answer (score 1):

```
Check this link :
```

http://jsfiddle.net/silpa/dyg86qbq/16/
    the above link with position relative and margin-top.
    Here is the link with position absolute for first div and margin-top for second div.
    [http://jsfiddle.net/silpa/dyg86qbq/22/](http://jsfiddle.net/silpa/dyg86qbq/16/)

Answer (score 1):

You can also give css like this

```
#div1 {
  background: yellow;
  width:100%;
}
#div2 {
  background: pink;
  position: relative;
  **clear:both;**
  width:100%; 
}
#div3 {
  background: gray;
  width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont user padding to set high for divs. Padding is used for different purposes.

```
div {
    height:50px;

}
#div1 {
    background: yellow;
}
#div2 {
    background: pink;
}
#div3 {
    background: gray;
}
```

Comment: Sorry this doesn's address the problem.

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: You are using relative position, you have to use then javascript to do that